# python subprocess running jar gives error

Tags: java, python, jar, subprocess

Running this command in the terminal works fine:

```
java -jar file.jar --arg1 --arg2 pathTofile
```

When I then try to do this from the python code using following code:

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'file.jar', '--arg1' , '--arg2' , 'pathTofile'])
```

I get an IllegalArugmentException for --arg1.

Any ideas on why this could generate a problem?

Comment: Can you modify or debug the Java program?

Comment: Linux and cannot debug the Java program, the java one works fine

Comment: the code in the question is fine. your answer indicates that the issue is that you put several command-line parameters into a single list item. The rule is simple: one parameter per item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figuered it out.
When using the subprocess routine in python you need to quote the option and concurrent value seperatly

eg:

```
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'file.jar', '-option', 'valueForThisOption', '-option', 'valueForThisOption', 'pathToFile'])
```

putting the -option and value in one quote generates this error.
I have read somewhere that you can only put the -option and value in one quote if you put shell=True at the end. (untested)

Comment: Depending on the called program, you can write `'--arg=itsParameter'` in one argument.

Answer (score 1):

@Benst - I encountered the same problem, this is what works for me:

`subprocess.call(['java', '-Dparam1=paramValue1', '-Dparam2=paramValue2', '-jar', 'filename.jar']);`

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry but this is not the solution. I have This: ['java', '-jar', 'pdfbox-app-1.8.8.jar', 'ExtractText', 'Content.pdf', 'Content.pdf.txt'] and does not work. It gives Usage: java [-options] class [args...]. ...

Comment: @alemol - your usage is incorrect, look closely at the syntax...'-jar' and the   'filename.jar' should be at the end of the code...

Comment: Following the correct syntax: subprocess.call(['java', 'ExtractText', 'somepdf.pdf', 'sometxt.txt', '-jar', 'pdfbox-app-1.8.8.jar']) gives: Could not find or load main class ExtractText.
So, How to call a module (with this usage) in python subprocess.call?:
java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar ExtractText [OPTIONS] <inputfile> [Text file]